# How Do I run Localhost?

Tags: xampp, localhost

Hi I would like to figure out how i can run local host. I keep getting an error of Port 480. My page is unable to load. I check my browser compatibility already.Cheers.

Comment: What does `http://localhost` say ?

Comment: I do not understand your question sir.

Comment: Try pasting the url on your browser and let know the output. Also, you don't require 480 port here. 80 will do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856184/how-do-i-run-localhost?noredirect=1#comment26068142_17856184

Comment: you could try http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps certain programmes such as skype could have blocked off your port.

Comment: Hmm i see. I will try to turn off my skype

Comment: @user2610122 You don't need to uninstall, just change the port of skype, Simple thing

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=206884&sid=aab0b1a93c15c8e0b4daa7d929b48933):

```
Listen and ServerName directive in \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf for Port 80
Listen, <VirtualHost> and ServerName directive in \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf for Port 443
```

You need to change the observed ports in your XAMPP control panel v3 settings too.

or if the problem is skype:

"*Why don't you configure Skype not to use ports 80 and 443?
Thats a simply checkbox in the Skype configuration.*"

Explanation here:

http://www.absolutewillynilly.com/computer/skype-xampp-port-conflict/

```
Skype >tools>options>advanced>connections > untick use port 80 and 443 as alternatives - restart skype
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stop Teamviewer / Skype. Check if your firewall blocks the port. Check if u correctly started the apache webserver.

And then you can reach your localhost via `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`